# Класс (скрипт, функция) проверки беклинков

Tags: php, классы

Сабж. Очень хочется под php 5.3.8
Нашел с использованием устаревших функций, ковыряться лень 
p.s. беклинк = обратная ссылка..
дополняю вопрос.
 - Класс (функция) должен проверять наличие определенного url на определенной странице другого сайта.

- ссылка есть если:
- - нет тега noindex
- - нет rel="nofollow"
- - нет вышеуказанного в файле robots.txt
- класс не должен использовать устаревшие функции типа eregi split и тп.

Почему бы самому не написать? Я слаб в регулярках, очень слаб, это, наверное то, в чем я не буду силен никогда..

Comment: А что скрипт должен с ними делать?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, есть страницы, на которых нужно проверить ссылку на себя? Что мешает получить страницы через file_get_contents и через preg_match получить нужные ссылки?

Или тут другой смысл?

**Добавлено.**

Регулярка примерно такая:

```
preg_match_all('/<a(.*)<\/a>/', $page_content, $links);
```

Здесь в `$links[0]` будут все ссылки страницы. Их можно перебрать в цикле с условием `if(strpos($links[0][$i], 'http://ваш_сайт') !== FALSE)`. Так узнаете, есть ссылка на ваш сайт или нет. По тому же принципу проверяется на "nofollow".

robots.txt читается построчно с помошью file() и так же сравнивается

Если на сайте есть ссылка на ваш сайт, то можно получить все блоки, которые закрыты:

```
preg_match('/<noindex>(.*)<\/noindex>/Uis', $page_content, $noindexes)
```

`$noindexes[0]` в цикле проверяется по условию if выше.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, я саму последовательность действий понимаю, просто чувствую, что на создание правильного регулярного выражения у меня уйдут месяцы, а это, по сути, все, из чего скрипт должен состоять.

Comment: Регулярка примерно такая:
preg_match_all('/<a(.*)<\/a>/', $page_content, $links);

Здесь в $links[0] будут все ссылки страницы. Их можно перебрать в цикле с условием if(strpos($links[0][$i], 'http://ваш_сайт') !== FALSE). Так узнаете, есть ссылка на ваш сайт или нет. По тому же принципу проверяется на "nofollow".

robots.txt читается построчно с помошью file() и так же сравнивается

Если на сайте есть ссылка на ваш сайт, то можно получить все блоки, которые закрыты: preg_match('/<noindex>(.*)<\/noindex>/Uis', $page_content, $noindexes), $noindexes[0] в цикле проверяется по условию if выше.

Comment: регулярку повторю с пробелами _, т.к. экранируются тут
preg_match_all('/__<_a_(_._*_)_<_\_/_a_>_/', $page_content, $links);

Comment: @dem это отдельные моменты, не могли бы сделать одну регулярку, выбирающую только наличие ссылки, которую надо проверить, т.е. если она находится внутри noindex - значит ее нет, если у нее есть rel="nofollow" - значит ее нет
аналогичо с роботс.